# Unable to call a parameterized javascript function on my page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript function as follows:

```
  function textCounter(field, rem, maxlimit) {
        if (field.value.length > maxlimit)
            field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
        else
            rem.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
    }
```

Here I am trying to set the value in a textbox(rem) on the basis of length of string in another multiline textbox (field).
On my page load I am trying to call it as shown below:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "testFunction", "textCounter(txtRemark," + txtRemarksRem.ClientID + ", '2000')", true);
```

But it does not seem to work.
What am i doing wrong here.

Issue that I am trying to solve is that onkey up and keydown attribute of multiline textbox I am able to call the function and set correct valut in counter textbox(rem) but on page load its value is again set to default.
 If there is any other solution, please suggest.

```
txtRemark.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "textCounter(this," + txtRemarksRem.ClientID + ", '2000')");
        txtRemark.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "textCounter(this," + txtRemarksRem.ClientID + ", '2000')");
```

The above code seems to work fine(setting the counter value on keyup or down.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the client id of both  textbox(rem) and textbox (field)., if the event is not attached to it.

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "testFunction", "textCounter(" + txtRemark.ClientID + "," + txtRemarksRem.ClientID + ", '2000')", true);
```

And then in your JS function

```
function textCounter(f, r, maxlimit) {
        //get the refernce of both element in dom by their client id
        var field =  document.getElementById(f);
        var rem = document.getElementById(r);
        //now this code would run correctly
        if (field.value.length > maxlimit)
            field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
        else
            rem.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
    }
```

Comment: I did the same .Still the counter textbox is resetting to max value on page load on some activity although data has been entered in the multiline textbox.As soon as we click there then the key up or key down seem to be called and counter value is set to correct value.

Comment: Well I think I did not get your issue correctly. Let me re-read what your problem is